# SQL Syntax run operations in between records?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a mysql database with a table in it. This table consists of the some of the following information. It has values in one column with months Jan-May. So five months. On the adjacent column, there are "Counts" with integer values to each month. Bear in mind that there can be duplicate values of the months. So, for example, a snippet of the table could read
January  |    5
January  |    10
February |    1
March    |    20
April    |    23
April    |    34
April    |    43
May      |    9
There are a lot more records (160). Say the average of the month is running some sql command like
select month, avg(count) from tablename group by month. However, this divides the sum of counts for each month by the number of records. A true average would divide the sum of the counts by the number of days in each month. So I have the following statements,

```
   select month, sum(count)/31 from trendsummary.traffictype where month like 'January';
   select month, sum(count)/28 from trendsummary.traffictype where month like 'February';
   select month, sum(count)/31 from trendsummary.traffictype where month like 'March';
   select month, sum(count)/30 from trendsummary.traffictype where month like 'April';
   select month, sum(count)/31 from trendsummary.traffictype where month like 'May';
```

This gives me the averages for the counts for each month. So the question is...what would be the syntax if I wanted an average of the averages of Jan-April? So... I want to have statements that would take the averages (based on the number of days of the month) for each of the months, and then take the average of the averages for January, February, March, And April and spit that value out? How would one go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could update your formatting a bit, this is hard to chew on ;-)

Comment: use case case to group the records together like `case when month in ('January', 'February','March' then '1st Quarter' when month in 'April','May','June' then '2nd Quarter'`  then group on that new key

Comment: What do you mean update the formatting? I apologize I should've mentioned that I'm about two weeks in since I ever even began programming. So any lingo or statements made will probably fly right over my head. What do you mean I should update the formatting?

Comment: So this case groups these months together...can I then apply an operation to each case? How would that work if I need to divide each month by its own unique number of days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try that :

```
select month, sum(count)/(31+28+31+30) 
from trendsummary.traffictype 
where month in ( 'January' , 'February','March','April' );
```

Comment: This one works! Thank you. However... say I were exporting this result into a chart. I understand this may not be something you've looked into...but the result from the above statement gives the average under the month january. In a chart this would then have the value coming from january. Is there a way to provide an alias of some sort for that result set?

Comment: didnt understand . can you edit your question and put example ?

Comment: I will have to do that in a while because I currently don't have access to the information. I didn't want to keep you waiting. I'll post an example of what I am asking tonight. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: you welcome ! , you can post other question with your second objectif if you want.

Comment: That is probably what I will do. Check out my profile tonight for the new question.

Comment: Hello. I solved that issue I mentioned yesterday. However, I posted another related question. If you have the time I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Union the selects and enclose them in parentheses and treat that as you data source as in this example:

```
select avg(*) from (
 select month, sum(count)/31 as average from ...
 union select ...
 union select ...
)
```

remember that most sql engines will require to name the computed expression column like I did (*as average*) at least in the first select of all union selects.

Comment: This one works as well! I just personally found the above answer more friendly. Just a personal choice, nothing against you! Both answers were so simple I almost feel bad for asking. I guess it requires a certain level of genius to think of the simple things though. Thanks again.